# Disappearing a button Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, button

HI am working in Actionscript 3.0, and I have crated a button that jumps to a different frame in the timeline, this is my code:

```
var newnextb = new nextb();

newnextb.x = 185;
newnextb.y = 260; 
stage.addChild(newnextb);

newnextb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,gClick);


function gClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndPlay("getMap");

}
```

and it works, but how do i make the button disappear after it has been clicked??

Answer (score 0):

Add `newnextb.visible = false;` in the event handler assuming `nextb()` is a display object.

Comment: sorry I am new to flash, what is the event handler??

Comment: @PaulinaJones Sorry for the delay. In your case the event handler is `gClick()`, so put the above mentioned code after `gotoAndPlay("getMap");`

Comment: HI when i do that- it comes up with.. Acces to undefined property newnextb- this is what my code looks like :

newbutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,gClick);


function gClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
 gotoAndPlay("getMap");
 newnextb.visible = false;

}

Thanks so much for your help and for responding!!

Comment: @PaulinaJones Hmm... then it is *possible* that your `nextb()` class does not extend a base class with the `visible` property, which is why you are getting that error. Did you write the `nextb()` class?

Comment: Ok I had an error with my code, but I managed to fix it. However the button still dosnt disappear. Were exactly do I past the newnextb.visible = false;?? does it look like this: otoAndPlay("getMap")newnextb.visible = false;??

Comment: Yes it should look like `gotoAndPlay("getMap"); newnextb.visible = false;`. Do you have access to the class definition and see what base class it extends?

Comment: OK i managed to fix it!!!! THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!!! your help was amazing!! :D

Answer (score 0):

On the line after

```
gotoAndPlay("getMap");
```

add the line

```
event.target.visible = false;
```

Comment: `this` refers to the current class, most likely the MovieClip which is displaying the main content of the application. `this.visible = false`, if I am not mistake, will hide the main MovieClip and all of its contents. In other words, everything should go away. =(